# Django form and internationalisation - wrong language for a label

Tags: django, forms, translation

I have a problem while displaying a form in my Django website.

My forms.py form :

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class FiltreMonoForm(forms.Form):
    orth = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False, label=_('orth').capitalize())
```

My view in views.py:

```
from .forms import FiltreMonoForm

def monollist(request, page=1):
    if request.GET:
        form = FiltreMonoForm(request.GET.copy())
    else:
        form = FiltreMonoForm()
    return render(request, 'lexics/listemonol.html', locals())
```

And in my template listemonol.html:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

When displaying, my form have the "orth" label in the wrong language.

I added a translated variable in my view to verify, this one is in the correct language when I display it in my template.

Someone has an idea to have my label in the correct language too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generally recommend people to not use `.upper()` on strings that are to be translated, and instead rely on CSS (e.g. `text-transform: uppercase`).

Manipulating translated strings has always created a lot of problems for me.

Comment: That's the problem. When I remove "capitalize()", my code works fine.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing ugettext_lazy using '_' , your import statement is the problem..

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
```

should be

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: I made a mistake when copying my text. In my original file, I had "ugettext_lazy as _". I edited my post.